# Styling chrome scroll bar like facebook chat scroll bar?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, scrollbar

I tried many ways but they are not good as i want. I want srcoll bar auto hide when inactive, show when scrolling. Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all you need to get a scrollbar like facebook.

/******* WebKit Scrollbar for webkit browsers *******/

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    height: 6px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button
{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But it's not auto hide when not in use. I don't want it take position of screen.
<img src="http://i752.photobucket.com/albums/xx166/alexviean/Untitled-1.png" width="100%" height="100%">